# Having Excel Recognize Text alongside Time as having a numerical value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I currently have each day of the week with the following rows below:  Start Time, Stop Time, Total Hours.  I have utilized the Data Validation function to create drop down menus for each of these columns; the majority of the options are times (ex. 9:30am).  To calculate the total hours I have the following formula:

```
 =(IF(J14<I14,J14+1,J14)-I14)*24
```

which works perfectly...however, I also need them to be able to choose "OFF, PTO, HOL" from the drop down menu and have those words recognized as having a total value of (O,8,8).  I have tried using the following formula:

```
=IF(I11:J11={"OFF"},0), IF(I11:J11={"PTO","HOL"},8)
```

and it has not worked, I have also tried using a `SUMIFS` formula with no luck... any ideas?

Comment: I think part of your post is missing. But if you are talking about the am/pm in the times, you can simply ignore them *if the cells are formatted as `Time`*

Comment: I sense that you have a problem, but I can’t quite make out what it is. Are you saying that, on a day when an employee is off (e.g., holiday, PTO, or whatever), you want to enter a fake start time and stop time of midnight and 8 AM? If so, where does the user *enter* the “OFF” code? Are you willing to have a “destructive” solution, in which, once an actual start time has been entered, you can’t change your mind and say that the employee was off that day?  PS. Do you have a strategy for handling off-days for people who work overnight shifts?

Comment: Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score -1):

Your Formula should be written like below:

```
{=IF(OR(I11:J11="PTO",I11:J11="HOL"),8,0)}
```

or

```
{=IF(OR(I11:J11={"PTO"},I11:J11={"HOL"}),8,0)}
```

Or, *if you want to test OFF also then write the Formula like this,*

```
{=IF(OR(I11:J11={"PTO"},I11:J11={"HOL"}),8,IF(I11:J11={"OFF"},0,""))}
```

**N.B.** Finish all the Formulas with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.